# sepearating out the data os a psydo array in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, discord

Thanks to Antonio Narkevich on another questions i was able to echo/log the data I'm pulling from an external JSON page into my node.js project but i can't figure out how to target and address particular elements of the fetch data which i know is in some array format but i cant figure out the syntax to address the particulars.

```
request({url: 'https://mee6.xyz/levels/267482689529970698?json=1'})
//So I'm getting all the players records

.pipe(JSONStream.parse('players.*'))
.pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
}));//.pipe(es.mapSync(function (data)
```

notably my log shows data like

```
{ avatar: 'b2339bb2e2424e596501bf83299b736f',
  discriminator: '1056',
  id: '215014325910241281',
  lvl: 1,
  lvl_xp: 155,
  name: 'Weird Peanutbutter science',
  total_xp: 172,
  xp: 72,
  xp_percent: 46 }
{ avatar: 'a03a2a149b6e1c8371861d8cf4b4385a',
  discriminator: '3672',
  id: '253735468770918400',
  lvl: 0,
  lvl_xp: 100,
  name: 'DDS Studios (Baron)',
  total_xp: 87,
  xp: 87,
  xp_percent: 87 }
```

but i'm having trouble splitting that into data I can manipulate:

ie:

```
if (INTERNALVAR == data[i].id){//do something}
```

or

```
if (numOfPerks <= data[i].lvl){//add another perk}
```

I've bee trying to sort the data into an array with no luck. I do know I can do console.log(data.lvl) and get a output of just all the levels, and they are line delimited so they must be in an array of some sort already iIjust can't figure out how I can access say data[2].lvl or search through them with a foreach loop.

Comment: Since you're expecting an array, shouldn't your console output look like: [{}, {}] ?

Comment: that's what i'm trying to do but i cant find the syntax to do it